# Google Cloud API Gateway supports file upload?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

It is posible to configure a gcp api gateway to handle a file text upload?

I get errors when try to generate an api config

```
     location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "http: cyclic message field \'google.protobuf.ListValue.values\' referred to by message \'HandleTextRequest\' in method \'method 1.pfe_reg_api_v3_uat_0n7ex0cswoe9t_apigateway_pfe_crun_cloud_goog.HandleText\' cannot be mapped as an HTTP parameter."
```

My current config is as follows

```
  "/gateway/handleText": 
    post:
      description: "Uploads a file."
      operationId: "handleText"
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: file
          type: file
          description: The file to upload.
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success."
          schema:
            type: string
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please describe your use case? You can upload the files directly to Google Cloud Storage using [Signed Urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). Also you should consider that there might be some limitation on the size of the file uploaded, depending on the backend ( App Engine, Cloud Function s, Cloud Run)

Comment: Thanks Marian I checked in the docs that GCP Api Gateway does not supports file upload

Comment: @JuanCarlosVergaraSantos could you share the documentation link for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check in the docs Api Gateway does not supports file uploads, I used other procedure to upload the file, after that I call the Api Gateway to process it

Comment: Can you share the URL for the documentation? Because the following docs says that it can process form-data:
https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/passing-data

Answer (score 1):

Since GCP API Gateway actually does not do any processing and only acts as a gateway I am assuming you mean you want to upload your file and then forward it.
Assuming that, I was able to upload images using form-data to GCP API Gateway and then further forward it to my Google Cloud Function.
Basically, I just attached my file using form data and sent the request via Postman, and the GCP API Gateway automatically forwarded it to "x-google-backend address".

The [link](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/passing-data) from GCP API Gateways also mentions that it can process form-data but doesn't explain how.

Edit: I have written a article with the config code that explains how to do the same.[Link to the article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/exploring-google-cloud-api-gateway-with-google-cloud-functions-ff56c1c96cc9)

Comment: Can you provide the code? I'm also trying to upload but when I try to upload the api config it gives the same error of the question.

Comment: Hi
I wrote an article with all the possible info you will need and also the actual working config code:
[link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/exploring-google-cloud-api-gateway-with-google-cloud-functions-ff56c1c96cc9)

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#file_upload

Seems like google api gateway doesn't support it. `type: file` config fails for me.